# Execute an async function before scenario triggers on codeceptjs

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, automated-tests, exceljs, codeceptjs

I am wanting to run a async function which will fetch the data for testing. This data is then passed to `Data()` hook in `codeceptjs`.

I have tried hooks and event listeners like "`Before()`, `BeforeSuite()` and `event.all.before`" and even a customized event listener but all seem to execute after the `Data()` hook. Putting the feature and scenario inside a function where fetch method is called before feature and scenario is also not working.

Async fetch call => Data() hook is called => Scenario is executed.

This is the flow of functions I am wanting.

Comment: https://github.com/codeceptjs/CodeceptJS/issues/436
It says that they added generator support a few years ago, you can try it

Comment: Hi, I looked at the link but this solution did not work out for me.